Synchronize Android clock using GNSS time
My app is connecting to a bluetooth device that uses GNSS time for its logging, so I want to synchronize my Android clock to GNSS time to combine my logs based on time.
Since Android 12, GNSS time synchronization is available, but I'm not sure how to enable it. I tried displaying config_autoTimeSourcesPriority with adb shell settings list [secure|system|global], but it did not show up. It appears that GNSS time synchronization is not on by default.
I think I may be able to root my Android and add a Fabricated Runtime Resource Overlay to override the default configuration, but I wanted to make sure this is a possibility before starting down this path...
Why can't I list the current state of config_autoTimeSourcesPriority? Would rooting and using an RRO work? Or is there a simpler solution?

You should be able to see the values of config_autoTimeSourcesPriority by inspecting the file core/res/res/values/config.xml.
To enable GNSS as a time source, you must set config_enableGnssTimeUpdateService to true and add gnss to the list of sources in config_autoTimeSourcesPriority (these can both be done by modifying the config file mentioned above).
Sources:
https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/time/gnss-time-detection#implement 
https://source.android.com/docs/automotive/time/automatic_time_detection#gnss

That documentation is for device manufacturers.

@Crag, I notice that now. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.
